# jQuery - How to access multiple XMLE children, some with same name

Tags: jquery, xml, nodes

I have an XMLE document that has a given structure (I cannot change it), and it goes like this:

```
<index>
<letter>
<title>A</title>
<mainTerm>
  <title>Some description</title>
  <code>Q87.1</code>
</mainTerm>
<mainTerm>
  <title>Another Description</title>
  <see>Some reference to other entries</see>
</mainTerm>
<mainTerm>
  <title>Another term<nemod>(-some) (detail)</nemod></title>
  <code>F44.4</code>
</mainTerm>
<mainTerm>
  <title>A more detailed term</title>
  <seeAlso>similar terms</seeAlso>
  <term level="1">
    <title>acute</title>
    <code>R10.0</code>
  </term>
  <term level="1">
    <title>angina</title>
    <code>K55.1</code>
  </term>
 </mainTerm>
</letter>
</index>
```

What I'm trying to do is use jQuery to access the contents of this file, and to build a table with it.

Problem is I'm having trouble accessing certain nodes properly.

Here is the jQuery to access the xml file:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'index.xml', // name of file you want to parse
dataType: "xml",
success: parse,
error: function(){alert("Error: Something went wrong");}
});
```

And here is the script I am trying to use to build the table:

```
function parse(document){
$(document).find("letter").each(function(){

$code = ($(this).find('code').text());
$desc = ($(this)).find('mainTerm->title').text();

//Build table
$("#content").append(
  '<table><tr><th>Code</th><th>Description</th></tr><tr><td> '+$code+' </td>    <td> '+$desc+' </td></tr></table>'
);                 
});
}
```

The $code variable works, but the $desc doesn't. How do I access the text of the node index->letter->mainTerm->title? Note there is another node called "title" higher up, which I don't need.

Appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Tried this? `$desc = $(this).find('mainTerm title').text();`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @winseybash, it woks now! It was easier than I thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$desc = $(this).find('mainTerm title').text();
```

It selects the `title` within the `mainTerm` element of the selected item.

Read more on [element selection](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/).

Comment: Thanks again, @winseybash! Thank you for the link, too, it is very helpful, though I find it hard to find tutorials that go in depth on how to parse / process complex xml files, with multiple subnodes...

Comment: @Cucurigu selecting XML elements is done in exactly the same way as HTML elements so there should be plenty of tutorials around for that.